# Compilers Hierachy for EBNF notation

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, compiler-construction, bnf, ebnf

I am developing a new programming language for my university assignment, in which I have to create it's variable definition form based on the instructions I am given by. As soon as, I create them I must create the EBNF notation, the railroad diagram and the LEX program.

What I need (and yes I've Googled quite a bit) is a simpler example or instructions that I can take a look at so that I can understand the general hierarchy. Something with variable declarations, function declarations, loops, assignments, operations etc but on a much smaller and simpler scale than all of C written in BNF. Thus, I will understand how to formulate the EBNF notation by myself.

As you may suspect, I am completely new in the compilers spectrum and by all means I am not asking you to provide me any solutions. My whole point is to learn!

Comment: Don't you have some kind of textbook and/or study materials? That should have lots of examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, all the resources I found don't provide such information.

Comment: One first step would be to find a language with syntax similar to yours and try to find its grammar. Even though it may not be EBNF, sometimes it is possible to 'translate' the grammar to the notation that you need.

Comment: My assignment provides that the variable definition for the language I have to create must start with the word "var", then the name of the variables of the same type separated by commas but the rules of the variable definition must follow the rules of the C language. I thought that I must use the BNF syntax for C, combined the one I just mentioned. Am I right?

Comment: @Alex_Pap take a look at pascal ebnf notation. They define variables the way you described in pascal.

Comment: Thank you, I completed my project based on exactly that. Didn't have the time to mention it here earlier. Now I will try to create the LEX program.

Answer (score 1):

To any whom may concern for future reference:

I completed my assignment by using the Pascal EBNF notation which was pretty close to my assignment's instructions I was given. To be more specific, I was provided that the variable definition for the language I had to create must start with the word "var", then the name of the variables of the same type are followed separated by commas. With that in my mind, I used the following Pascal EBNF notation.

```
var_part = var [identifier { "," identifier } ":" type "κ" { }].

identifier = letter { letter | digit }.

type = "integer" | "real" | "char" | "boolean".

letter = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" | "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" | "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z" | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z".

digit = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9".
```

The first line of the EBNF, I created myself based on the following syntax diagram which is the variable declaration part of Pascal language.

[image]

and the following syntax diagram which is the part that analyses the type of the variables,

[image]